# dyld: Library not loaded running command

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, bioinformatics

I downloaded some binaries for my mac from https://github.com/rcedgar/muscle/releases/tag/v5.0.1428

I moved it to a folder, ran

```
chmod +x /Users/schuylersloman/Documents/CODE/BIO_LAB/SENIOR_YEAR/muscle_v5.0.1428_osx
```

and then when I tried running

```
./muscle_v5.0.1428_osx muscle  -align ny_ct.fasta -output alignment.fasta
```

I Get the error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/11/libgomp.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/schuylersloman/Documents/CODE/BIO_LAB/SENIOR_YEAR/./muscle_v5.0.1428_osx
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Any help on how to fix this or what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the author of muscle. Try rebuilding using the new build system described in the github wiki, which at the time of writing (8th Dec 2022) is in the rce-dev branch.

Comment: Thanks so much Robert Eager. I really appreciate your response and I will definitely look at the girhub wiki and try to work it out. At school I use muscle in my lab regularly so it is totally cool that you responded to this. That is the beauty of the internet I suppose. Thanks again!